# Unable to install .pfx certificate on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, vpn, keytool, pfx, pkcs#12

I have to checkout from a git repo on a private network. I have the required pfx certificate installed on my system and I can fetch/clone the repo using the command line while I am connected to the VPN after providing the password in the prompt. I can't however do this on Jenkins. I tried installing the pfx in Jenkins credential manager but the file isn't even uploading. Jenkins no more provides vpn plugin support. Is there a way to do this?

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://root@10.247.186.70/srv/git/leaveRepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: connect to host 10.247.186.70 port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Have you tried providing read permission to the cert directory for the user id that runs the Jenkins service?

Comment: @Mike - Yes I have.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation:

- The credential must be a private key credential if the remote git repository is accessed with the ssh protocol.
- The credential must be a username / password credential if the remote git repository is accessed with http or https protocol.

So, you should export a private key from pfx bundle and add it to Jenkins using credentials of type `SSH username with private key`.

Comment: SSH username with private key gives me the following error: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://rCaused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://user@host:/abc.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr:root@<host>: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. I can access the repo thrubash

Comment: did you check the private key is working? why do you use such a format `ssh://user@host:/abc.git`? can you try `git@github.com:group/project.git`?

Comment: that's because we are not using github services. Just git bash for version control. The repo is stored on a private network. The private network doesn't have internet connection due to security policy reasons. I have this certificate installed on my system and can clone the repo from vpn using git bash terminal after entering a password in the prompt. But when I store the same private key on credential manager in jenkins and give this password as passphrase , i get error status code 128 permission denied on git fetch.

Comment: well, from the original image I see that you are using Jenkins plugin, it probably not compatible with your case. Try to configure `ssh-agent` service. you can start with https://dev.to/solrevdev/windows-does-not-remember-git-password-lmh and https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases